# doPost and getParameter()

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

First timer here on StackOverflow. I have a question concerning req.getParamter. I have a class Alumni(). Within this Alumni class I have a PersonalAddress class that is used to store things like the city, state, street, etc. As im pulling data out of my JSP page I'm running into an error when I try to pull data into the structs. An example may explain better.

```
public Alumni() {
  String name;
  int age;
  PersonalAddress personaladdress;

  public Alumni(){}
  ... (constuctors,getters and setters within each class, yadda yadda)
}
```

In my doPost, variables like name are being pulled fine from the html page. Example:

```
Alumni a = new Alumni();

 a.setName(req.getParameter("name"));

 But once I get to the "structs" it will not let me do so. Example

 a.personaladdress.setStreet(req.getParameter("street"));
```

Any ideas why I'm not allowed to use getParameter("street") in my personaladdress struct?

Comment: It's always a good idea to post the error message(s) too

Comment: In Java, it is usual to access member variables through accessor methods, e.g. your Alumni class would have a getPersonalAddress() method. It is also good practice to initialise your class members to avoid unexpected errors. Have you tried to inspect the request before using it?

Comment: The problem has been solved. Thanks for the comments it is great appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try and answer with some questions =)

- What is the exact error message you get?
- Do you have a getter for PersonalAddress of the for getPersonaladdress() in the Alumni class? Is the case exactly correct - uppercase 'A' in getPersonalAddress() not getPersonaladdress()?

If it's neither of the above and you're seeing a NullPointerException then it's probably because you've not created the PersonalAddress in the new Alumni before trying to set the street (which you can do without the getter syntax).

```
Alumni a = new Alumni();
a.setPersonalAddress(new PersonalAddress();
a.personalAddress.street(req.getParameter("street"));
```

Comment: Through you're questions about my questions I have solved the problem. Thank you very much for the help. +100000 points